# Non clustered indexes for special case

Tags: sql-server, indexing, non-clustered-index

TABLE **SellerTransactions**

```
 string SellerId,
 string ProductId,
 DateTime CreateDate,
 string BankNumber,
 string Name(name+' '+surname+' 'alias),
 string Comments,
 decimal Amount
 etc...
```

what would be the best case scenario for search/filtering with non clustered index when we search by sellerID, ProductIds, CreateDate and sometimes Amount/ BankNumber.. should the non clustered index be only on (first sellerID, ProductIds, CreateDate) columns or on all possible columns where the search might happen (a single big non clustered index).

Query will always contain  (sellerID, ProductIds, CreateDate) and sometimes additionally bankNumber/Amount.

Say 90% of the time sellerID, ProductIds, CreateDate will be searched and 10% of the time sellerID, ProductIds, CreateDate & Amount or bankNumber.

I was thinking having a nonclustered index on (`sellerID, ProductIds, CreateDate`) and separate ones for amount and bank number.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a filtered index to improve the performance of your query.

What is a filtered index?

> Filtered index is used to get some portion of table.

i.e. a filtered index applies a filter on index which improves query performance.

For more info, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017

**Syntax**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX  Non_ClustredIndexName
ON Table(ColumnName)
WHERE ColumnName = @ColumnValue
```

Example as per your table:

1.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FI_Employee_DOJ
ON tbl_SellerTransactions(ST_Name)
WHERE ST_Name IS NOT NULL
```

2.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NonCluster_sellerID
ON tbl_SellerTransactions(sellerID)
WHERE sellerID BETWEEN '100' AND '500'
```

3.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FI_Employee_DOJ
ON tbl_SellerTransactions(ST_Name)
INCLUDE(SellerId,amt,ProductId,BankNumber) --Including remaining columns in the index
WHERE ST_Name IS NOT NULL
```

**Notice**

1. Filtered index can be used on views only if filtered indexes are persisted views
2. Filtered indexes are not created fulltext indexes

Comment: Hi, thanks @marc_s, but I believe all values in my table will not be null. \on which I will searhing/filtering/sorting...